# How to prevent user from deleting a row from database if something refers to it

Tags: php, database, laravel

I am developing a dashboard and the user can create Internet Providers and after that he can associate packets to it. The problem is, if the user delete after that the Internet provider associated, the webpage crash when I go to the packets, because its trying to access to a non existing Internet Provider. So I want to prevent if the Internet Provider is refered 1 or more times in another table, the user cant delet it.

Internet Provider Delete function:

```
    public function destroy(Internet $provider)
{
    $oldName = $provider->name;
    $oldUrlFoto = $provider->image_url;
    try {

        Storage::delete('public/provider/' . $oldUrlFoto);
        $provider->delete();
        return redirect()->route('admin.providers')
            ->with('alert-msg', 'The provider "' . $provider->name . '" was deleted!')
            ->with('alert-type', 'success');
    } catch (\Throwable $th) {
        // $th é a exceção lançada pelo sistema - por norma, erro ocorre no servidor BD MySQL
        // Descomentar a próxima linha para verificar qual a informação que a exceção tem

        if ($th->errorInfo[1] == 1451) {   // 1451 - MySQL Error number for "Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (%s)"
            return redirect()->route('admin.providers')
                ->with('alert-msg', 'We cant delete this provider "' . $oldName . '", because its already in use!')
                ->with('alert-type', 'danger');
        } else {
            return redirect()->route('admin.providers')
                ->with('alert-msg', 'We cant delete this provider "' . $oldName . '". Error: ' . $th->errorInfo[2])
                ->with('alert-type', 'danger');
        }
    }
}
```

Packet model and Internet Provider Model:

```
class Packets extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = ['internet_provider_id', 'name', 'price'];

    public function internetProvider()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Internet::class, 'internet_provider_id');
    }
}

class Internet extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'image_url'];

    public function packets()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Packets::class);
    }
}
```

Migrations:

```
Schema::create('internet', function (Blueprint $table) {

    $table->bigInteger('id')->unsigned()->autoIncrement();
    $table->string('name', 50);
    $table->string('image_url');

    $table->timestamps();
    // Clientes podem ser apagados com "soft deletes"
    $table->softDeletes();
});

Schema::create('packets', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigInteger('id')->unsigned()->autoIncrement();
    $table->bigInteger('internet_provider_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('internet_provider_id')->references('id')->on('providers');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('price');
   

    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes();
});
```

Comment: This is done on database level with foreign key constraints

Comment: @LarsStegelitz I dont know what I need to do, can you give me a tip?

Comment: google://laravel+database+foreign+key

Comment: show us the migration for this table

Comment: just add ->onDelete('cascade'); to your foreign key and that should do it

Comment: @dz0nika Doesnt work for me but I figured out another way to do it! Thanks anyways